# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 (word2vec)

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have the same problem with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504411/how-to-deal-with-this-value-error i got an error at this snippet:

```
def load_bin_vec(fname, vocab)   
"""
Loads 300x1 word vecs from Google (Mikolov) word2vec
"""
word_vecs = {}
with open(fname, "rb") as f:
    header = f.readline()
    vocab_size, layer1_size = map(int, header.split())
    binary_len = np.dtype('float32').itemsize * layer1_size
    for line in xrange(vocab_size):
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'if' How can i solve it?

Comment: Obviously the first line of the file (filename passed as `fname`) you open does not only contain integer representations. What is the content of this file and how is it created? You must either repair the file you read to match the required format, or you must adapt your code to the different file format.

Comment: Give an example what header is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Am still new in python and anaconda, but after some search, I installed anaconda(latest version), gensim (latest version).
On process_data.py, at line 126, I changed it from  w2v_file = sys.argv[1](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)  to  w2v_file = sys.argv[1:] . read about python sys.argv [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)

You will do the same on conv_net_sent.py on the sys.argv[] at lines 293, 294.
On module process_data.py, line 64,change fname to "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin".
This modules will run well. 
I only noted that when running the conv_net_sent.py module, at training phase, I got the python.exe stopped working error.
When using spider on anaconda, i got an error about : device gpu0 is not available  (error: cuda unavailable),which am working on at the moment. 
I hope this helps.
Regards